# Ho to show All Versions of “Append Changes to Existing Text” Data in mail using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

How to get plain text from "Append Changes to Existing Text” using workflow in mail content

Answer (score 0):

Append Changes to Existing Text will always give latest entry in workflow.

There is a work around to have all the entries in the workflow.

For this you need to create another multi line column which will store the entries of all the versions of actual multi line column. Only thing is that, this column should be hidden on New/Edit Forms so that users can not modify its value from UI.

Following are the steps:

1. Create a column, say `HiddenHistoryColumn` in the list of type `multi line of text`.
2. Create a list workflow on that list on item create and update.
3. Create three local workflow variables of string type as e.g. `PreEntries`, `LatestEntry`, `CombinedEntries`
4. Following is the workflow steps. (you may change these as per your need)

   ```
   If CurrentItem:Column1 is not empty
       set Variable:PreEntries to CurrentItem:HiddenHistoryColumn
       then set Variable:LatestEntry to CurrentItem:Column1
       then set Variable:CombinedEntries to [%Current Item:Modified By%] ([%Current Item:Modified%]): [%Variable:LatestEntry%] <NewLine> [%Variable:PreEntries%]  //Format it as per your need in string builder dialog box
       then set HiddenHistoryColumn to Variable:CombinedEntries
       then Email User1
   ```
5. Use `HiddenHistoryColumn` in Email Body to get all version of "Append Changes to Existing"